# How to make text, right justified in file type of input?

Tags: html

In HTML input file type attribute, how to make file path right justified, which I am getting by browsing?

```
<input type=file id='id' class='file' />
    $('#id').css('text-align','right')
```

is not working.

I tried

```
$('#id').attr('style','text-align:right');
```

But no use. If I use class instead of id then also it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cant modify the style of the input file , but you can use other methods to style it indirectly..

Try this one out.

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

http://www.kavoir.com/2009/02/styling-file-upload-select-input-control-input-typefile.html

Comment: yeah i tried that link , but in that case whole element will be right justified. I want file path and name to be right justified.

Comment: I mean to say if my file is C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\bang.txt then i want to display end of this file in textbox , that is right justification. But it is showing left justification

Comment: it is possible, but you really need to create a fake input to display it.. the second one is easier to integrate